# Не отображается дата с включенными маленькими иконками в панели задач

Tags: windows, windows-10

Раньше на старом билде винды у меня отображалось время и дата на панели задач с включенными маленькими иконками на панели задач. Сейчас же отображается только время, хотя мне кажется место для даты там есть, возможно дело в размере шрифта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Мне нужно такое, но только с маленькими иконками (иначе слишком уж большая панель задач).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Информация о Windows:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я долго искал решение этой проблемы, но все варианты сводились к увеличению панели задач, что мне явно не подходило. Сегодня я наконец нашел решение, **НО для этого пришлось использовать постороннее ПО**. Ссылочка на репозиторий программы: [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock).
Вот чего получилось добиться:
[image: Результат программы]