# Как включить отображение даты на панели задач в windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Вот так оно отображалось раньше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так у меня отображается время сейчас. (У меня панель задач вверху экрана, но это никак не влияет).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете есть следующее решение. Предлагается отключить пункт "Использовать маленькие кнопки панели задач" в настройках панели задач. Это действительно работает, но это решение мне не подходит. У меня довольно большой монитор, и полоса панели задач, если включить этот пункт, становится очень широкой (типа сантиметра 2 в высоту) и начинает прям мозолить глаза. (достаточно сравнить вторую и третью картинки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще один вариант есть на stackoverflow, но он подразумевает установку стороннего ПО, чего мне тоже хотелось бы избежать.([Не отображается дата с включенными маленькими иконками в панели задач](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291939))

upd. Оно у меня тоже чето не работает о_о

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что я сделал, перед тем как оно слетело.
У меня была другая проблема). Не отображался текст интерфейса в Adobe Reader. Я переустановил шрифты Segoe (видимо они были установлены некорректно) и все заработало, но увы, слетела дата. Больше я ничего не менял, в этом я уверен.

Помогите, хочу вернуть дату на панель задач, но не хочу широкую панель задач и стороннее ПО...

Самое интересное, что у меня уже была такая проблема, но как я ее решил я не помню(. Вероятно я тогда и сломал установленные шрифты и вот щас оно всплыло.

Comment: Если выбрать вариант отображения маленьких кнопок на панели задач, то должны отображаться только часы. Все верно. Оно не должно было работать, как на первом скриншоте. Причем там еще и шрифты без сглаживания.

Comment: Наверное там были снесены системные шрифты и заменены на более мелкие, без сглаживания. Оттого и помещалось.

Comment: *"У меня довольно большой монитор, и полоса панели задач, если включить этот пункт, становится очень широкой и начинает прям мозолить глаза."* - скорее наоборот, очень маленький монитор.